# connection to database with password containing dollar signs and exclamation marks

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am trying to open a connection using `psql` to a database.
The connection string looked like this

```
psql -A -t -c "sql query" postgresql://$1@$2/$3
```

Where I passed as first parameter

```
$1 = login:password
$2 = localhost:5432
$3 = dbname
```

It worked fined when login and password was pretty much standard like 123 and so on.

But when I try to connect using a password like `123412@15!12$` it fails with the incorrect password.

How to escape it property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use safer variable placing:

```
psql -A -t -c "sql query" "postgresql://${1}@${2}/${3}"
```

In addition parameters $1, $2, $3 should be passed as:

```
script.sh 'login:password' 'localhost:5432' 'dbname'
```